# python random error, do they have a fix yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/milena/python/vosenbMyach.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'math' (/Users/milena/python/math.py)
milena@Stevens-MBP python %
```

and the code that generated it

```
import random

def GetAnswer(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1 :
        return 'Bet on it'
    elif answerNumber == 2 :
        return 'It is certain'
    elif answerNumber == 3 :
        return 'It is decidly so'
    elif answerNumber == 4 :
        return 'Yes!'
    elif answerNumber == 5 :
        return 'Reply hazy, try again'
    elif answerNumber == 6 :
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 7 :
        return 'I need more information'
    elif answerNumber == 8 :
        return 'Concentarate!  Try Again!'
    elif answerNumber == 9 :
        return 'My reply is No!'
    elif answerNumber == 10 :
        return 'Outlook is not so goog'
    elif answerNumber == 11 :
        return 'Very Doubtful'
    elif answerNumber == 12 :
        return 'Pray'

print(GetAnswer(random.randint(1,12)))
```

Do I have to reinstall, did I do a screw up?

Comment: Seems like you have a Python script named `math.py` in `/Users/milena/python/` that's shadowing the module of the same name that's part of the standard library. Try renaming that file.

Answer (score 2):

The traceback indicates that you have created a file `math.py` in your working directory. When importing the random package it then attempts to import the `math.py` that you've created as opposed to the correct package. Rename your `math.py` and your program will run.

Comment: thank you.  I didn't know I did that.  Will reinstalling fix this?

Comment: I didn't create a math.py file.  How do I get rid of it?  Where is it?